# Create all combinations of two sets

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of strings, they are actually values of primary keys in database:

```
        List<string> hisSpecialtyKeysInDB = this.Repository.GetSpecialtyKeysOfThisProvider(providerKey);
        List<string> hisAddressKeysInDB = this.Repository.GetAddressKeysOfThisProvider(providerKey);
```

Either of them may or may not even have a value in it.

I want a combination of all possible combinations of these primary keys that these two lists might have. ( so for example if one has 3 items, the other has two items, I want to see six items)

I wrote this query below but its count is zero which is wrong. **In my test one of these had zero items in it** and the other had three, so I want three items to return. Can put the empty ones as string.Empty, that is fine by me.

```
        var temp = from ps in hisAddressKeysInDB
                   from pa in hisSpecialtyKeysInDB
        select new
        {
            PS = ps,
            PA = pa
        };

        int xxxxx = temp.Count();
```

Comment: If string.Empty is fine to represent an empty list why don't you just put it into an empty list?
`if (hisSpecialtyKeysInDB.Count == 0) hisSpecialtyKeysInDB.Add(string.Empty);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you need with the `DefaultIfEmpty` extension method. e.g.

```
var temp = from ps in hisAddressKeysInDB.DefaultIfEmpty("")
           from pa in hisSpecialtyKeysInDB.DefaultIfEmpty("")
           where ps != "" || pa != "" // This is to remove the edge case when both are empty
           select new
           {
               PS = ps,
               PA = pa
           };
```

Comment: still returns zero for count.

Comment: Sorry. I noticed after I post that the `where` condition was wrong. I had put an `&&` instead of an `||`.

Comment: One question: If for the default of empty value I choose another default value instead of empty string for example the word "NOP", then in your where clause do I also have to change those empty strings to "NOP" ?

Comment: Exactly. Each empty string should be replaced with your new default.